# How to extend Balana OpenAZ PEP to send requests to remote WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: xacml3, wso2-identity-server

What's the appropriate way to extend a Balana-OpenAZ based PEP to send XACML3 decision requests to a remote WSO2 Identity Server PDP?

Answer (score 0):

You want to send XACML decision request from PEP to Identity Server PDP.  Still Identity Server only supports SOAP based web service API, Thrift based API and WS-XACML.  Therefore i guess,  best way to start is using SOAP based web service API. You can find sample java based client from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/06/14/pep-client-for-wso2is-pdp/) to write a extension for  Balana-OpenAZ PEP.